# Using an ActiveX control in a C# project where Size(float, float, float) exists in the ocx

Tags: c#, activex

I am trying to write a program that utilizes a 3rd party ActiveX control in a .NET 3.5 project. I add it to my form using toolbox and it adds AxLEADLib, LEADLib, and stdole to my project's references.

However the code that is auto generated puts in

```
this.axLEAD1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
```

But in AxLEAD there exists both

```
public System.Drawing.Size Size {get; set;}
public virtual short Size(float fWidth, float fHeight, short iFlags)
```

So when I try to set the size of the control on my form, in the designer.cs I get the error `Cannot assign to 'Size' because it is a 'method group'`. What can I do to get around this issue? How do I set my size of my control?

This is a project being ported over from VB6 and there does not appear to be anything special done in the old project to handle this.

Comment: I tried to declare class in c# with method and property as you proposed - compiler failed to compile that (member with the same name already declared). I wonder how it works for your ActiveX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get Hans' solution to work right but I did find a workaround. I change the erroring line to

```
((Control)this.axLEAD1).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
```

And it works fine. I just need to correct it every time the code regenerates.

Answer (score 1):

This is a .NET specific failure mode, caused by the AxHost wrapper.  The Size property is inherited from Control and collides with the Size method from the ActiveX control.

Not so easy to fix.  Run AxImp.exe with the /source command line option so it generates code instead of an assembly.  You can then edit the code and add it to your project.  Editing is tricky though since it is an inherited property.  Something like this:

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new Size Size { get; set; }

public Size Size2 { 
   get { return base.Size; }
   set { base.Size = value; }
}
```

The first one hides the Size property from the designer.  The Size2 property is what you can set in the designer.

Comment: I tried that but it gives the error `The type 'AxLEADLib.AxLEAD' already contains a definition for 'Size'`

Comment: I also tried renameing the function from size to size2 and it compiles fine, however when I try use the dll in my form it does not allow me to use it to add a control to the toolbox, is that normal?

Comment: When you add the generated source code file to your project, after compiling the control should appear at the top of the toolbox.  There's one option that controls this: Tools + Options, scroll down, Windows Forms Designer, General, AutoToolBoxPopulate = True.